# Virtualbox(linux - hdmi - TV )

Tags: mediaplayer, virtualbox, linux

Собираюсь запустить на ВБ линукс, а на нем запускать фильмы которые будут транслироваться на ТВ через HDMI. Все это делается, что бы продолжать работать за своим компом, а видео буду смотреть не я. Включу дублирование экрана, и выведу звук на ТВ, и вкл. фильм, сверну ВБ, и буду заниматься своими делами за компом. Скачиваю Ubuntu.
Подскажите получится ли это сделать, и относительно это оптимальный вариант (другого не нашел. Не хочу, что бы по ТВ видели чем я занимаюсь на ПК)?
И как все это лучше сделать?

Comment: А на виртуалке включить дублирование экрана (как на Win8) нельзя, что ли?

Comment: а чего-бы просто не показывать кино через mplayer на втором мониторе (телевизоре) ? звук туда выведите и всё, я так делаю. на tv и не будут видеть, если вы сами туда окно не утащите. (у вас хост на винде что-ли, ну там вроде тоже можно так сделать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@ALPHA](/users/20055/alpha), вообще это на биткод, но:

1. Создается виртуалка
2. Создается отдельный монитор внутри винды
3. На него переносится окно виртуалки и запускается в фулл скрин

Разделить контроль без дополнительного устройства в этом случае не получится, однако можно поднять на убунту vnc-server, пробросить порты и управлять виртуалкой с любого другого устройства.

Comment: а звук как вывести на второй монитор? винда же не умеет роутить аудио и ниодна программа не умеет роутить аудио с virtualbox

Comment: @JohnDoe создайте отдельный вопрос

Comment: уже создал, никто не знает или не хочет расказывать

Comment: @JohnDoe ну, комментарий сюда имеет еще более низкие шансы на ответ.